# react js input doesn't allow writing

Tags: reactjs

Hello i have two input when i click on it and try to write something it doesn't come out
and he doesn't allow writing I don't know why

code:

```
   import React, { Component } from 'react';

class LoginForm extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            login:'',
            password:'',
        };
        this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
        this.onChange = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
    }
    onSubmit(e){
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    onChange(e){
        this.state({[e.target.name]: e.target.value});
    }

  render() {
    const { errors, login, password, isLoading } = this.state;
    return (
        <form onSubmit={() => this.onSubmit}>
            <label for="login">Login</label>
            <input type="text" id="login" value={login}  onChange={(e) => this.onChange(e)} placeholder="Informe seu login" />
            <label for="password">Senha</label>
            <input type="password" id="password" value={password} onChange={(e) => this.onChange(e)}   placeholder="Informe sua senha"/>
        <button className="btnEnt" type="submit">Entrar</button>
    </form>
    )
  }
}

export default LoginForm;
```

I can't type anything in either input
I don't know where I went wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't passing any arguments to the handler. Also you are missing the property `name` for each input which is critical for accessing `event.target.name` in the change handler. Change it to the following for implicit passing of the event object:

```
<input type="text" name=“login” id="login" value={login}  onChange={this.onChange} placeholder="Informe seu login" />
// ...
<input type="password" name=“password” id="password" value={password} onChange={this.onChange}   placeholder="Informe sua senha"/>
```

Or change it to the following to actually pass the event argument to the handler:

```
<input type="text" id="login" name=“login” value={login}  onChange={(e) => this.onChange(e)} placeholder="Informe seu login" />
// ...
<input type="password" id="password" name=“password” value={password} onChange={(e) => this.onChange(e)}   placeholder="Informe sua senha"/>
```

The other issue is that you are trying to execute this.state instead of [this.setState](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html), change it to the following:

```
this.setState({[e.target.name]: e.target.value});
```

Here is an [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-q8mgx4) in action.

Comment: continued the same thing

Comment: Try the updated answer, I added name properties to each input. Which what was you were targeting in the handler but was missing on the inputs.

Comment: Your question still doesn’t have the name properties, this is critical for each input as you are targeting event.target.name in the handler. It will be undefined if not added to the inputs.

Comment: now i got error here: LoginForm.js:17 Uncaught TypeError: this.state is not a function

Comment: this.state({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value});

Comment: how could i fix this?

Comment: You are calling this.state instead of this.setState, I updated the answer

Comment: continued the same thing I don't know why

Comment: I modified how you passed me

Comment: You updated this.state to this.setState and you get the same error of that the function is not defined?

Comment: I tried a console.log on
 this.setState ({[e.target.name]: e.target.value});
and it's like undefined

Comment: Now I do not get error, but typing does not appear in my input

Comment: setState doesn’t return anything so trying to console log it won’t do anything, does the input update now? Does state change after that line is called?

Comment: Okay, let’s try something different, can you use stackblitz.com to create a working example and share the link?

Comment: Here is the updated answer that’s working https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-q8mgx4 you still havent added property `name` to the the inputs! As soon as you add the name property you should be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

I will give you the brief explanation here.

1. you are assigned empty value as input value. login in the state is having empty you assigned that right !

remove Value to the input.

```
<input type="text" name="login" onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} placeholder="Eg: xyz" required />

<input type="text" name="password" onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} placeholder="Eg: xyz" required />
```

add handle change function:

```
 handleChange(e) {
    let change = {}
    change[e.target.name] = e.target.value
    this.setState(change)
  }
```

The above handlechange function automatically assign values to state.

If you want to submit data:

```
onSubmit(){
 axios.post("www.yourURL.com", this.state).then(res=>{
 console.log(res
})
```

That's it.Happy coding...

Comment: thanks 
so I don't need this in my constructor:
        this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind (this);
        this.onChange = this.onSubmit.bind (this) ;?

Comment: And how do I get the value of what is written in login and password to send on my onsubmit?

Comment: Updated the answer check now